# CODE to let users to upload only images

Tags: php

I have upload.php file and I want the user to upload only an image. 
Can anyone please check my code and advise if it is ok or not?

```
$file_ext = strrchr($_FILES['my_files']['name'], '.');   // Get The File Extention In The Format Of , For Instance, .jpg, .gif or .php
$copy = copy($_FILES['my_files']['tmp_name'], "$idir" . $_FILES['my_files']['name']);   // Move Image From Temporary Location To Permanent Location
if ($copy) {   // If The Script Was Able To Copy The Image To It's Permanent Location
  print 'Image uploaded successfully.<br />';   // Was Able To Successfully Upload Image
   $nomDestination = "Img_".date("YmdHis").".".$extensionFichier;

   if($extensionFichier == 'jpg'){$destination = imagecreatefromjpeg("$idir" . $url);}
   else if($extensionFichier == 'gif'){$destination = imagecreatefromgif("$idir" . $url);}
    else if($extensionFichier == 'png'){$destination = imagecreatefrompng("$idir" . $url);}
     else if($extensionFichier == 'jpeg'){$destination = imagecreatefromjpeg("$idir" . $url);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works then it's ok but there's always a better way!

```
$allowed = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg'];
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['my_files']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
    // fail
}
else {
    // success
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied it from a project. Just replace zip with jpeg and add as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let user upload only image, You have to validate before copy function.I used to code with move_uploaded_file() function. Instead using if else, you can use array.

```
       $errors= array();
       $file_name = $_FILES['my_files']['name'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['my_files']['tmp_name'];
       $file_nameArr = explode('.',$file_name);

       $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_nameArr));

       $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

       if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
          $errors[]="Invalid file type.";
       }

       if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_path.$file_name);
       }
```

Also consider validating in client-side before uploading.

Comment: Tip: use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) with the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION `-option to get the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to verify that the file is an image and get a correct file extension programmatically, rather than trust whoever is uploading files to my server. You should do this before moving the file to a publicly accessible directory.

```
<?php
function getImageFileExtension($pathToImage)
{
    if(file_exists($pathToImage))
    {
        list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($pathToImage);

        $fileExtensions = array(
            IMAGETYPE_GIF => 'gif',
            IMAGETYPE_JPEG => 'jpg',
            IMAGETYPE_PNG => 'png',
            IMAGETYPE_WBMP => 'bmp',
            IMAGETYPE_XBM => 'xbm');

        if(!array_key_exists($type, $fileExtensions))
        {
            throw new Exception('File '.$pathToImage.' is not an image.');
        }

        return $fileExtensions[$type];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Image file '.$pathToImage.' not found.');
    }
}

try
{
    $allowed = ['gif', 'jpg', 'png'];
    $ext = getImageFileExtension($imgPath);

    if(!in_array($ext, $allowed))
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid image file');
    }

    print $ext."\n";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```